# Custom adapter implementation

Tags: android, adapter

I have a question, currently I am using CursorTreeAdapter however I want to change it to use any other data not just cursors, but to be honest im not sure how would I do that, I think implement some other adapter and then override needed methods? But could any one show me some way? I'm confused right now and don't know to what direction I should go.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes you can extend: [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can see this example:

```
public class FeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<FeedItem> items;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    FeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> list, int bgColor){
        items = list;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    @Override
    public FeedItem getItem(int index) {
        return items.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }   

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;

        if (null == convertView) {
                    row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.romanblack_feed_item, null);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.romanblack_rss_title);
        TextView pubdate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.romanblack_rss_pubdate);

                String titleString = items.get(position).getTitle();
                title.setText(titleString);

                if(items.get(position).getTextColor() != Color.TRANSPARENT){
            title.setTextColor(items.get(position).getTextColor());
                }else{
                    title.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                }

        pubdate.setText(items.get(position).getPubdate());

        return row;
    }

}
```

and layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/romanblack_feed_item"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#FFF">

    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/romanblack_rss_bg_feed" 
      android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:text="Title" 
            android:id="@+id/romanblack_rss_title" 
            android:textSize="14sp"             
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView 
            android:text="2011-01-01" 
            android:id="@+id/romanblack_rss_pubdate" 
            android:textSize="10sp"             
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```